# Query groups that contain a profile name

Tags: apex, soql

How can I query all groups that contain 'MY PROFILE NAME' as a member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group members are stored in `UserOrGroupId` in `GroupMember` object.
It is a reference field to another Group or User object.
And you can filter the profile name in User object.

So the SOQL is:

```sql
SELECT Group.Name 
FROM GroupMember 
WHERE UserOrGroupId IN 
    (SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Profile.Name = 'My Profile Name')
GROUP BY Group.Name
```

Comment: Thanks Hengky. Makes perfect sense.